# How to unmarshal XML file in apache camel

Tags: xml, routes, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I have two classes ItemsDto and ItemDto
they represent data from XML file

@XmlR

```
ootElement(name = "items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemsDto {

    @XmlElementRef
    private List<ItemDto> items;

    public List<ItemDto> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ItemDto> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

and another

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemDto {

    @XmlElement
    private int itemNo;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String description;
    @XmlElement
    private int number;
    @XmlElement
    private int rating;

    public ItemDto() {
    }

    public ItemDto(int itemNo, String name, String description, int number) {
        this.itemNo = itemNo;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.number = number;
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

and I have test.xml file

```
<items>
  <item>
    <itemNo>998</itemNo>
    <name>Rider Auto Part Generic Brakepad</name>
    <description>Basic brakepad for any motorbike</description>
    <number>100</number>
  </item>
</items>
```

I want to set a route to read from a file, but I don't know how to set unmarshaling part
I can't figure out what to do...

```
from("file:inputXML")
.unmarshal().  something
.process(exchange -> {
   System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    unmarshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(ItemsDto.class))).process(e-> exchange.getIn().getBody(ItemsDto.class);)
```

after that u can use this class in processor